# Are Subject Alternative Names compulsory for SSL in Jetty 9.4.18

Tags: security, ssl, keystore, jetty-9

Are Subject Alternative Names (SANs) in keystores compulsory while configuring SSL over Jetty server (version 9.4.18) ?  Is there a property which on being set , allows SSL configuration without SANs in the keystore ? Facing critical issues hence help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is a web server. The certificate sent by the server is validated by the client (web browser and others). Therefore the certificate provided by the server must match the expectation of the client. Subject Alternative Names are mandatory for years with some clients, notably with Google Chrome.